# Name (variable name) is not defined error

Tags: python

I have written the following code, but I always get the same error message says (NameError: name 'weight_kg' is not defined) again and again even i change the code pls help(P.S I am a beginner):

**First Try:**

```
def profile():
    name = input('Name: ')
    weight_kg = int(input('Weight(Kg): '))
    height_m = int(input('Height(M): '))

bmi_converter = (weight_kg / (height_m ** 2))

def bmi_result():
    print(name)
    if bmi < 25:
        print('Is not overweight!')
    else:
        print('Overweight!')

profile()
bmi_result()
```

**Second Try:**

```
def profile():
    name = input('Name: ')
    weight_kg = int(input('Weight(Kg): '))
    height_m = int(input('Height(M): '))
    bmi_converter()

def bmi_converter():
    bmi_formula = weight_kg / (height_m ** 2)
    bmi_result()


def bmi_result():
    print(name)
    if bmi < 25:
        print('Is not overweight!')
    else:
        print('Overweight!')

profile()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this into a class, where each object stores the bmi profile for each person.

```
class bmi_profile:
    def __init__(self, name, weight_kg, height_m):
        self.name = name
        self.weight_kg = weight_kg
        self.height_m = height_m
        self.bmi_result = weight_kg / (height_m ** 2)
  
    def print_bmi(self):
        print(self.name, end = ' ')
        if self.bmi_result < 25:
            print('Is not overweight!')
        else:
            print('Overweight!')

name = input('Name: ')
weight = float(input('Weight(Kg): '))
height = float(input('Height(M): '))

profile = bmi_profile(name, weight, height)
profile.print_bmi()
```

Output: (With input after the `:`)

```
Name: Jon
Weight(Kg): 60
Height(M): 1.80
Jon Is not overweight!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
def profile():
    name = input('Name: ')
    weight_kg = int(input('Weight(Kg): '))
    height_m = int(input('Height(M): '))
    bmi_converter(weight_kg, height_m, name)


def bmi_converter(weight_kg, height_m, name):
    bmi = weight_kg / (height_m ** 2)
    bmi_result(bmi, name)


def bmi_result(bmi, name):
    print(name)
    if bmi < 25:
        print('Is not overweight!')
    else:
        print('Overweight!')


profile()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# My first try
def profile():
  global weight_kg, height_m, name
  name = input('Name: ')
  weight_kg = int(input('Weight(Kg): '))
  height_m = int(input('Height(M): '))



def bmi_result():
    print(name)
    if bmi_converter < 25:
        print('Is not overweight!')
    else:
        print('Overweight!')

profile()

bmi_converter = (weight_kg / (height_m ** 2))        

bmi_result()
```

Nice attempt Jon. You need to use global variables then it will work. Also, you forgot to refer the correct variable `bmi_converter`

[image]

I get the above output.

Answer (score 1):

Your weight_kg, height_m and name variables scopes are in the profile function. So they cannot used in other functions. You can use these variables as parameters.

```
    def profile():
        name = input('Name: ')
        weight_kg = int(input('Weight(Kg): '))
        height_m = int(input('Height(M): '))
        bmi_converter(name,weight_kg, height_m)
    
    
    def bmi_converter(name,weight_kg, height_m):
        bmi_formula  = weight_kg / (height_m ** 2)
        bmi_result(bmi_formula , name)
    
    
    def bmi_result(bmi, name):
        print(name)
        if bmi < 25:
            print('Is not overweight!')
        else:
            print('Overweight!')
    
    
    profile()
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally make my code works thanks to all of you I scramble some of your code into mine and make it shorter and simplier here it is:

```
name = input('Name: ')
weight_kg = int(input('Weight(Kg): '))
height_m = int(input('Height(M): '))

def bmi_calculator(name, weight_kg, height_m):
    bmi = weight_kg / (height_m ** 2)
    if bmi < 25:
        print(name +' is not overweight!')
    else:
        print(name +' is overweight!')

result = bmi_calculator(name, weight_kg, height_m)
```

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please consider to vote up answers helped to solve the problem :-)